# utf8 in database - set default_charset in php.ini

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, php-ini, my.cnf

I have set utf8 in mysql database

now it shows

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+


+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

I have the below in the php code

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and

```
$con = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','database');
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Since I set utf8 in database, I am planning to remove

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

and

```
mysqli_query($database,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

from PHP code

I was told that I can remove the above code but I need to add

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

in the PHP code.

Instead of adding `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8")` in the code, can I set

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

in `php.ini`?

my.cnf is

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
default-character-set=utf8
default-collation=utf8_general_ci
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions in your question. They shouldn't be mixed like that. If it's a typo, fix your question.

Comment: please note that standard `UTF8` in MySQL is **NOT** the full UTF8 Character set. If you want/  need the full UTF8 character set saved in your database you need to use `UTF8mb4` in MySQL.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Machavity, fixed my question

Answer (score 2):

> Instead of adding `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8")` in the code, can I set 
>   `default_charset = "UTF-8"` in php.ini?

No, that does not affect the database connection character set.

And even the [MySQL extension settings](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php) offer nothing in that regard – and neither do [those for MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php).

It *is* a per-connection setting after all.

But if you put your code to establish the database connection into one file that you include wherever it is needed, that should be enough.

Comment: so, mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); is a must have after establishing database connection?

Comment: Unless you can configure the default value in the MySQL server settings directly: Yes. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client)

Comment: in my.cnf, I have [client] default-character-set=utf8 and [mysqld] default-character-set=utf8

Comment: Strongly recommend always putting it into your code. That way it your code is not dependent on the MySQL server configuration which could change over time.

Comment: Thanks @SteveE., just to know, if I have [client] default-character-set=utf8 and [mysqld] default-character-set=utf8 in my.cnf, can I avoid having mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); in the code?

Comment: The [client] section of my.cnf applies to the mysql command line tool. It does not affect the server. It really is better to be specific in your code about the connection character-set rather than leave it to configuration options. The impact on performance is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The question is in reference to MySQL so setting up a config in php.ini won't help much in this case.  What i suggest is to update the my.cnf file in mysql

more about my.cnf settings can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html)

```
[client] 
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld] 
character-set-server=utf8 
default-character-set=utf8 
default-collation=utf8_unicode_ci 
character-set-client = utf8
```

i took the above part from this [thread](https://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3553642.htm), which discusses the same issue but for both PHP and MySQL. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: I have updated my question with my.cnf
if I have those settings in my.cnf, can I avoid having mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); in the code?